# Delete an element in a matrix

Tags: matrices

I created a matrix, but how do I delete the numbers in the matrix?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{pgf}

\newcommand\gray{gray}

\newcommand\ColCell[1]{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1<.8?1:0}%
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0\relax\color{white}\fi
  \pgfmathparse{1-#1}%
  \expandafter\cellcolor\expandafter[%
    \expandafter\gray\expandafter]\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}#1}

\newcolumntype{E}{>{\collectcell\ColCell}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{c*{6}{|E}|}
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{hw} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{bx}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{wk} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{jg} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{cl}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{rn} \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 ving & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 xing & 0 & 0.92 & 0.08 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 king & 0 & 0.03 & 0.97 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 ging & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 ping & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 ning & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
\end{tabular}\par\bigskip
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, don't write them…

Comment: @Bernard yes when i delete them, the lines inside the matrix are deleted too

Comment: Do you stiill want to have black and grey cells, but without any content?

Comment: the lines will not be deleted if you just delete the entry

Comment: No they are deleted

Comment: No idea? ... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a phantom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{pgf}

\newcommand\gray{gray}

\newif\ifshowdata

\newcommand\ColCell[1]{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1<.8?1:0}%
  \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0\relax\color{white}\fi
  \pgfmathparse{1-#1}%
  \expandafter\cellcolor\expandafter[%
    \expandafter\gray\expandafter]\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}%
  \ifshowdata#1\else\phantom{#1}\fi
}

\newcolumntype{E}{>{\collectcell\ColCell}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{c*{6}{|E}|}
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{hw} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{bx} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{wk} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{jg} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{cl} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{rn} \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 ving & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 xing & 0 & 0.92 & 0.08 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|} 
 king & 0 & 0.03 & 0.97 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 ging & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 ping & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 ning & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

% now we show the data
\showdatatrue

\noindent\begin{tabular}{c*{6}{|E}|}
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{hw} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{bx} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{wk} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{jg} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{cl} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{rn} \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 ving & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 xing & 0 & 0.92 & 0.08 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|} 
 king & 0 & 0.03 & 0.97 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 ging & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 ping & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 ning & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here I have defined an `Z` column type that suppresses the content, but still adds the shading. So, replacing the `E` column with `Z` produces:

[image]

The `Y` column type suppresses the shading as well.  You can also mix and match as desired. So, for instance, using

```
\begin{tabular}{c |Z|Y|E|E|Z|Z|}
```

yields:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{pgf}

\newcommand\gray{gray}

\newcommand\ColCell[1]{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1<.8?1:0}%
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0\relax\color{white}\fi
  \pgfmathparse{1-#1}%
  \expandafter\cellcolor\expandafter[%
    \expandafter\gray\expandafter]\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}#1}

\newcommand*{\DeleteEntry}[1]{%
  \hphantom{#1}%
}%
\newcommand*{\ColoredEmptyEntry}[1]{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1<.8?1:0}%
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0\relax\color{white}\fi
  \pgfmathparse{1-#1}%
  \expandafter\cellcolor\expandafter[%
    \expandafter\gray\expandafter]\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}\hphantom{#1}%
}%

\newcolumntype{E}{>{\collectcell\ColCell}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\collectcell\DeleteEntry}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\collectcell\ColoredEmptyEntry}c<{\endcollectcell}}


\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{c |Z|Z|Z|Z|Z|Z|}
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{hw} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{bx} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{wk} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{jg} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{cl} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{rn} \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 ving & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 xing & 0 & 0.92 & 0.08 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|} 
 king & 0 & 0.03 & 0.97 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 ging & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 ping & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 ning & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
\end{tabular}\par\bigskip

\noindent\begin{tabular}{c |Y|Y|E|E|Z|Z|}
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{hw} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{bx} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{wk} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{jg} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{cl} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{rn} \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 ving & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 xing & 0 & 0.92 & 0.08 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|} 
 king & 0 & 0.03 & 0.97 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 ging & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 ping & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
 ning & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hhline{~*6{|-}|}
\end{tabular}\par\bigskip

\end{document}
```